# Patterns in Spacy

Tags: python, spacy

Im creating a simple programme using Spacy to learn how to use it. I have created a pattern to recognize when the user put "1 day" or "3 weeks", like this:

```
[{"IS_DIGIT": True},{"TEXT":"days"}],
[{"IS_DIGIT": True},{"TEXT":"day"}])
```

However, I also want it to recognize when the user put "4 days" instead. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve that with:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

txt = "This will take 1 day. That will take 3 days. It may take up to 3 weeks."
doc = nlp(txt)

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern = [{"IS_DIGIT":True},{"LEMMA":{"REGEX":"day|week|month|year"}}]
matcher.add("HERE_IS_YOUR_MATCH",None, pattern)

matches = matcher(doc)

for match_id, start, end in matches:
    print(nlp.vocab.strings[match_id], doc[start:end])
HERE_IS_YOUR_MATCH 1 day
HERE_IS_YOUR_MATCH 3 days
HERE_IS_YOUR_MATCH 3 weeks
```

Comment: Alright, thanks! Do you know, by the way, how can I do it so the pattern recognizes both " 2 days" and "four days" for example?

Comment: You may wish to check like_ num token attribute